# Tensorflow: How to access Variables from a model imported from Caffe?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm using the [tensorflow-deeplab-resnet model](https://github.com/DrSleep/tensorflow-deeplab-resnet) which transfers the Resnet model implemented in Caffe to tensorflow using [caffe-tensorflow](https://github.com/ethereon/caffe-tensorflow).

I'd like to know how I can access individual variables from the model that was imported from Caffe so I can check what is going wrong.

I tried

```
allTrainVars = tf.trainable_variables()
for f in allTrainVars:
  print f.name
```

which outputs

```
[...]
res5c_branch2c/weights:0
bn5c_branch2c/scale:0
bn5c_branch2c/offset:0
bn5c_branch2c/mean:0
bn5c_branch2c/variance:0
fc1_voc12_c0/weights:0
fc1_voc12_c0/biases:0
fc1_voc12_c1/weights:0
fc1_voc12_c1/biases:0
fc1_voc12_c2/weights:0
fc1_voc12_c2/biases:0
fc1_voc12_c3/weights:0
fc1_voc12_c3/biases:
```

The `fc1_voc12_c*` layers are the interesting layers that need to be reinitialized randomly. But when I try to access them and add a logging to the variable like this

```
var = [v for v in tf.trainable_variables() if v.name == "fc1_voc12_c0/weights:0"][0]
tf.summary.histogram("fc1_voc12_c0/weights_0", var)
```

I can't see that variable in tensorboard. The only thing that is displayed in tensorboard is the graph itself.

How can I access these variables in order to monitor them in tensorboard?
Can I infer the correct names of the variables that I'd like to monitor by just looking at the graph (see picture)?

[image]

**Edit**
I edited the focus of my question a little since there was a bug which has been fixed by now by the author of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it's acutally working in the way described in the question. I just needed to completely shutdown tensorboard and restart tensorboard for every new log file that I created.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify my understanding: You're trying to restore some part of the model from an old version, and initialize the rest randomly.

If that's true, you can use `tf.contrib.framework.init_from_checkpoint` to initialize body of your model from the old checkpoint. The rest of the model (output layer) should be initialized randomly based on how you created it.

Comment: Well I did not really create it, it was automatically generated from the deeplab-resnet model built in caffe. Thats why I don't know how to get access to the individual variables and enforce the random initialization